# Assigning Entire Private Array via class properties

Tags: vba, excel, class, properties

I have an array that is a fixed size as a Private variable for one of my classes. Is there a way to set up a get/let property that will allow me to pass the entire array to the object, or will I have to assign the values independently? What about with a public function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe you are talking about sth like that.
A class with the name cArray

```
Option Explicit

Dim mArr(1 To 5) As String

Property Get aValue() as Variant
    aValue = mArr
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    mArr(1) = "Test1"
    mArr(2) = "Test2"
    mArr(3) = "Test3"
    mArr(4) = "Test4"
    mArr(5) = "Test5"
End Sub`
```

And for testing

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim c As cArray
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Long

    Set c = New cArray
    v = c.aValue
    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        Debug.Print v(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Update: for the let part you will need a loop

```
Property Let aValue(nVal As Variant)

Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(nVal) To UBound(nVal)
        mArr(i) = nVal(i)
    Next i

End Property
```

Comment: I didn't think to try and return the value as a Variant. That seems to have worked for the Get part. I was mostly asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Just added the let property. There you will need a loop.